# Firebase Dynamic Link not working on the app launch

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I have created a `dynamic link` that opens the app when clicked. The link also contains keys that open a specific page. Here is my code:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([Any]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
    return self.handleFirebaseDynamicLink(userActivity: userActivity)
}
```

This works when the application is running in the background. But I also need the dynamic link to check the `URL` and open the specified page when it is launched for the first time. What can I do to solve this issue?

I found an accepted answer here: [Firebase Dynamic Link not working if app is CLOSED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42868622/firebase-dynamic-link-not-working-if-app-is-closed)
But unfortunately, I could not understand what it meant and I cannot comment on that answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You call your `handleFirebaseDynamicLink` method **only** from `application(_:continue:restorationHandler:)` this is the problem.

From [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsapplicationdelegate/1428471-application):

> **application(_:continue:restorationHandler:)**
>
> The app calls this method when it receives the data associated with the user activity. Use the data stored in the NSUserActivity object to re-create the user’s activity. This method is your opportunity to update your app so that it can perform the associated task.

So this method is called only if your app is `Suspended` and becomes `Active` again because of `NSUserActivity`. If you want to process data on application launch, you need to use another method, that is called when your app is become `Active` from `Not running`. And this is `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` method. [Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TheAppLifeCycle/TheAppLifeCycle.html) you can read more about apps lifecycle.

From [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1622921-application):

> **application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)**
>
> Use this method to complete your app’s initialization and make any final tweaks. This method is called after state restoration has occurred but before your app’s window and other UI have been presented.

And that's what says in the answer that you've provided. All you need to do is handle the initial data using this method at `AppDelegate`. You can extract your `NSUserActivity` from `launchOptions` using the following code.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    let activityKey = NSString(string: "UIApplicationLaunchOptionsUserActivityKey")
    if let userActivityDict = launchOptions?[.userActivityDictionary] as? [NSObject : AnyObject],
       let userActivity = userActivityDict[key] as? NSUserActivity {
        return self.handleFirebaseDynamicLink(userActivity: userActivity)
    }
    return true
}
```

Hope it helps you.